# Angular 2 documentation / is there an ngdocs for angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a bit of experience with angular 2, but I'm still relatively new to the Framework. While looking around, I discovered something called ngdocs. It's very nice because it creates a sort of documentation / wiki area for you based on the comments in your code. (similar to js docs). However, it seems to be written exclusively for use with angular 1.XX.

I've done some searching around, but can't seem to find anything that would provide similar functionality for angular 2. Does anyone know if there is something similar to ng-docs for angular 2?

Comment: Some things to note:

- I'm using angular 2 with typescript.

- I've tried using ngdocs with angular 2. I can't really use it because:
   1. The generated documentation is using angular 1.
   2. The typescript compiler often strips comments (they need to be in certain areas).
   3. the @ngdoc tag does not let me organize the docs in a way that make sense for angular 2. (i.e. build errors on component tag)

Also, I'm using ngdocs with gulp.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I have found so far is [TypeDoc](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc).  It is not specific to angular but it will create some documentation for you based off of the typescript.  It does appear to lack the ability to do certain things you may be used to with ngDoc (live examples and such).

Answer (score 3):

There is also a project called Compodoc (https://medium.com/vincent-ogloblinsky/compodoc-documentation-tool-for-angular-2-applications-44ec650e01a8), which generates documentation specific for Angular 2/4.

They are using normal comments and have added support of markdown syntax as well.

Comment: the only thing I miss is a possibility to add demo buttons and link them to custom components.